# Debian 9 - IO address already in use? unable to boot

Tags: debian, boot

**Introduction**

I booted up my computer as usual, which is dual-booted with Debian 9 and Windows 10.

**The problem**

As soon as I entered my Debian partition I received an error message, which hangs and doesn't allow me to boot into my Debian partition.

[image: Error message]

**My attempts**

I deleted the Debian partition and installed Ubuntu to make sure if it was an issue with Debian kernel itself, as suspected Ubuntu partition is bootable and functions correctly.

I then attempted to Install Debian 8, which installed successfully and booted without problems. I then upgraded to Debian 9 rebooted my PC and received the same error again and hangs, unable to boot. I also installed Debian testing, and received the same error on boot.

What is this error? What does it mean, and how would I go about fixing this?

***NOTE***: the error still appears with DE installed but still boots

- Works when I install with a desktop environment
- Doesn't work and hangs at the error when I don't install a desktop environment  (the latter is what I want)

Comment: You have completely misdiagnosed your problem. The last message on the screen is not necessarily the cause of a boot problem like this, at all. (On AskUbuntu, [this is a much-repeated misdiagnosis](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=starting+version+219).) You need to _ensure that your system even has the bootstrap goal_ of bringing up a TUI login on your first KVT, _read your logs_ to find out how far your system had got through the bootstrap and what it was trying to do at that point, boot your system _in verbose mode_ so that a lot more is logged, and _make a question based upon those_.

Answer (score 4):

The `sp5100_tco` error means that the watchdog driver for the AMD SB700 and SB800 series chipsets cannot load because the watchdog's I/O address is already in use. Unless you've actively using the watchdog, this error should not halt the boot process.

If you suspect the module, you could blacklist it with a boot option `modprobe.blacklist=sp5100_tco` on an already-installed system, or `sp5100_tco.blacklist=yes` when running the Debian installer.

You might also edit the boot options in the GRUB bootloader to remove the default boot option `quiet` to see more boot messages. Those would give you a more complete picture about where the boot process hangs and what things it has completed successfully before hanging.

For example, it would be important to know if `/dev/sda5` is your Debian root partition or not: if contains the root filesystem, the hang might happen while the system is still on initramfs or transitioning from it to the real root filesystem. If `/dev/sda5` is some other filesystem, the system is quite a bit further along in the boot process and different troubleshooting methods would be called for.

Comment: I feel a bit overwhelmed here, will give it a shot, Debian with no desktop environment hangs on this error. Debian +xfce works however seems to launch it's gui and be fine. I'm at my wits end, would wiping the entire hdd stop this error from appearing ?

Comment: I've blacklisted it. However even though the error message doesn't appear, it still hangs.

Comment: Then the error message was unrelated to the cause of the hang, and you'll need to get more information. When you edit the boot options in GRUB, option `quiet` should be already there by default. Remove it to see more boot messages.